# Cookie setting fails for login with Google but works for login with email/password

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, session-cookies

I'm trying to create an API server that handles signup and login. It could be either with email/password or using google. Once the user signed up or logged in, they get a session cookie, and get redirected to their profile to complete. This works well for email/password handler but for google the user never gets a session cookie set for some reason.

Code for saving user and setting cookie in google login handler:

```
user = models.User{
    Email:      email,
    GoogleUser: true,
}

if err := user.Insert(); err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error creating new user: %v", err)
    http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}

// Create session cookie and redirect to profile page
err = utils.CreateSessionCookie(w, r, user.Email)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error creating session cookie: %v", err)
    http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
     return
}

http.Redirect(w, r, "/profile/edit", http.StatusSeeOther)
return
```

Code for creating a new cookie:

```
// CreateSessionCookie creates a session cookie
func CreateSessionCookie(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, email string) error {
    log.Printf("Creating session cookie for %s", email)
    encoded, err := SessionCookieHandler.Encode(SessionCookieName, email)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error encoding session cookie: %v", err)
        return err
    }

    log.Printf("Session cookie encoded: %s", encoded)

    SessionCookie.Value = encoded
    SessionCookie.Expires = time.Now().Add(SessionCookieMaxAge * time.Second)
    SessionCookie.HttpOnly = true
    http.SetCookie(w, SessionCookie)

    log.Printf("Session cookie created: %v", SessionCookie)

    return nil
}
```